# Problem with Cache Factory

Tags: magento2, cache, products, export

When i will export the products, this messagens show **Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image\CacheFactory does not exist** in MAGENTO 2.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CacheFactory is a class which is generated by Magento. In the developer mode it is generated on the fly, when first time requested by PHP autoloader. In production mode it should be generated ahead of time. It can be missing, if classes haven't been regenerated after the code update.

Which mode are you running at? If it is production, did you upgrade the code of Magento since switching to production?

The easiest way to fix the problem is to remove var/di and var/generation directories.